# Auth0 JWT Token validation in PHP

Tags: php, angular, jwt, auth0

I'm attempting to send an Auth0 JWT from my client to my server and have the token validated. I send the token_id returned from the auth0 authentication to my server via AuthHttp headers and i can obtain it without an issue within PHP.

Short and Simple:

- Angular 2 Auth0 JWT gets sent to the PHP server.
- How do i validate the signature is correct?

I have the Secret ID, i have the JWT helper class with the encode and decode.

How do i check the header and body = the signature of the JWT sent over, if that's even the correct way to do it.

Edit:

I pass in my token which is

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvbG93aWUuZXUuYXV0aDAuY29tXC8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwNDY4ODk4NjgxNzEwNjQ3Mjc5MCIsImF1ZCI6IlYwWWVaREliYmVGdEJ4Z3F2UkNzVkFjWWxscXpaZGlNIiwiZXhwIjoxNDc4NzMxNjIzLCJpYXQiOjE0Nzg2OTU2MjN9._uyKrxJ0lPR-tEPjOFiI5ygeiM689gqURcIfG4sWkWc

In which i then get the body of this token and make it into an array

> ```
> Array (
> [iss] => https://lowie.eu.auth0.com/
> [sub] => google-oauth2|104688986817106472790
> [aud] => V0YeZDIbbeFtBxgqvRCsVAcYllqzZdiM
> [exp] => 1478731623
> [iat] => 1478695623 )
> ```

Once i have the array, this is my payload right?

// Here's an image of the token being verified as right
[https://gyazo.com/93777863d988d8c6ef0fc4ea50755949](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83IjN.png)

so why does the below code not give me the same token?

```
$jwt = JWT::encode($bodyArray, "SuperSecureSecretSecret");
```

yet i receive this back

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvd2llLmV1LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwNDY4ODk4NjgxNzEwNjQ3Mjc5MCIsImF1ZCI6IlYwWWVaREliYmVGdEJ4Z3F2UkNzVkFjWWxscXpaZGlNIiwiZXhwIjoxNDc4NzMxNjIzLCJpYXQiOjE0Nzg2OTU2MjN9.6lEg_0h0zytQZVBqDe-ZIS5PoSkFAJhWtRYSgaDCesY

Answer (score 0):

You should use an existing library that supports the type of JWT signature you're using. For a quick reference on your available options for PHP check the *Libraries* section in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

Using an existing library is preferred in most situations, however, it's also important to do some assessment on the quality of the library.

For JWT signature validation read this article ([Critical vulnerabilities in JSON Web Token libraries](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/)) to ensure that your usage of the libraries does not lead to possible vulnerabilities.

---

**Update:**

The tokens are different because they are signed with different keys and the payload also differs; the `iss` in one is `"https://lowie.eu.auth0.com/"` and on the other is `"https:\/\/lowie.eu.auth0.com\/"`. You can check that by decoding the payload with a Base64 decoder and look at the raw output.

More importantly, you should not be creating any tokens, just validating that they are valid and were issued by the trusted issuer to which you delegated the actual authentication process.

Comment: I used the firebase one, there's no specific one for Auth0, see the updated question please

Comment: JWT is a standard so any compliant library for your technology choice will do.

Comment: I understand the payload issue although the key i use is correct and copied directly from auth0. Are you sure the key is incorrect?

Comment: My statement about the different keys was purely based on observing the behavior in jwt.io using the key you included in the snippet. One of the tokens was marked as valid and the other one wasn't so assumed it used a different key. Let me repeat it, I've may have messed something.

Comment: It still marks the second token has invalid despite selecting the same key; however, it might be a bug if you're sure you used the same key. Try to look into the payload difference, it might end up solving the signature discrepancy meaning this behavior in jwt.io is a bug.

Comment: In jwt.io, i have to select the base64 encoded box, and in auth0 it says "The Client Secret is a base64 encoded string." yet it's just a plain string, does that matter?

Comment: Yeah, that's it, if I select the checkbox I still get only one of the two tokens valid, but it's the opposite. The issue is that one of the tokens is being created assuming `SuperSecureSecretSecret` is a base64 encoded key and the other is created assuming `SuperSecureSecretSecret` is the raw key. Both are valid interpretations because base64 includes all the english alphabet letters so you need to ensure to use the same interpretation everywhere.

Comment: I've switch account @JoãoAngelo in hope to chat as i needed 20 reputation to do so. I cannot seem to find a message you button, is there any chance i can use something external to quickly resolve my issue, shouldn't take more than 5 minutes.

Comment: @JoãoAngelo i've got the same payload for the JWT:encode(payload), JWT::decode(returned encode) as my token but i don't know if it's valid as the sign in the JWT helper proceeds regardless. If i change the token incoming, both versions change and it's returned although it should not work because it's no longer valid.

Comment: You should've received an invite to chat; and the reputation thing should also no longer be an issue.